# perl null or empty detection

Tags: string, perl, hash

I have a hash containing results of matching substrings.  I want to print a message if there is no matching between the string.  I've tried the following and it didn't work.

```
foreach (keys %d) { 
    if ($_ eq "") {
        print "no matches"; # and i've tried (if defined $_
    } else {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

the % d is filled this way (it contains matched substrings)  :

```
foreach (my $i=0;$i<length($seq1)-$k;$i+=1) { 
    my $common=substr($seq1,$i,$k); 
    if ($seq2=~/$common/) {
        $d{$common}++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. How about giving us a sample `%d` and the desired output you want for that sample `%d`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I finally see what you are trying to accomplish. You think that checking if the keys in `%d` equal the empty string, then there were no matches in your loop. This is false. If there are no matches, then there are no keys, and the loop will never execute.

Unfortunately, you cannot check if `%d` contains no values that way. You need something like:

```
unless (%d) { 
    print "No matches\n";
} else {
    print "$_\n" for keys %d;
}
```

Comment: print dumper is giving nothing when the $_ is empty

Comment: @AWRAM It should not print nothing, it should print `$VAR1 = ''`. And was it your intention to check if the *key* of the hash was the empty string? E.g. if you had `$d{''} = "some value"`?

Comment: I meant i didnt get anything, when it's set it gives $var1='AC..' but when not it didnt return anything. I need to check the $_ itselfs

Comment: @AWRAM No, Data::Dumper will *always* print something. "It didnt return anything" is a false statement. If you are using `print Dumper $_`, then you *are* checking `$_` itself.

Comment: @AWRAM I think I finally figured out what you were trying to do. Check my updated answer.

Comment: If you're looking for the number of keys in the hash, use `keys %d`. A hash in scalar context gives you the hash statistics, which only accidentally works out.

Comment: @briandfoy In [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) it says `If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash is empty.` It continues to elaborate on the part on which you are apparently confused: `If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a slash.` There's no accidents here, and I'd ask you to take more care where you place your downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have an iteration over all existing keys and check if the are an empty string, that's I guess not what you want.

Try

```
if (defined $d{$_})
```

or if it is set to "" then

```
if ($d{$_} eq "")
```

To be more helpfull, one would have to know how your hash is filled.

You need to initialize also the non matching values. In your code you can add an

```
if ($seq2=~/$common/) {
    $d{$common}++;
}
else 
{ $d{$common} = 0 unless (exists($d{common})); }
```

and then check

```
if ($d{$_} > 0)
```

Comment: foreach (my $i=0;$i<length($seq1)-$k;$i+=1)
      {
 my $common=substr($seq1,$i,$k);
        if ($seq2=~/$common/)
        {
          $d{$common}++;
        }
     }

Comment: you initialize only those $common, that do match. I edited some more lines in the code above.

Comment: on the else {... line it gives me syntax error ( I correct $d{$common}